# .NET register services for interface, base class and sub class dependency injection

Tags: asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

My interface and classes

```
public interface INoteService {
 SomeMethod();
}

public class NoteService : INoteService {
private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

public NoteService(IAuthenticationService authenticationService){
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
}
//some code ...
}

public class CompanyNoteService : NoteService {

private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

public CompanyNoteService (IAuthenticationService authenticationService) : base (authenticationService) { }
//some code...
//overriding methods
}
```

The controller

```
public class NoteController : Controller
    {

        private readonly INoteService _noteService;

        public NoteController (INoteService noteService)
        {
            _noteService= noteService;
        }
}
```

I want to call the methods of CompanyNoteService in the controller, using dependency injection.
I registered my services like this:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
services.AddScoped<INoteService, CompanyNoteService>();
```

But I keep receiving a null value for _authenticationService.
The following example works, but I want to use my overridden methods.

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
services.AddScoped<INoteService, NoteService>();
```

How do I register my services in order to get things work?

Comment: The behavior you are describing, does not match the code you posted; the problem, therefore, isn't reproducible. Please change your code examples into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). Without an MRE, we will not be able to help you. Most likely, your actual `CompanyNoteService` looks different from the example you posted.

Comment: I guess `_authenticationService` should be `protected readonly`, not private, and only be defined once in the base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem comes from the duplicate declaration of `_authenticationService`.
Difficult to tell without a whole code, but I think you are setting the base class `_authenticationService` while you try to read the subclass `_authenticationService` (which remains `null`).
You should try something like this.

```
public interface INoteService {
 SomeMethod();
}

public class NoteService : INoteService {
  protected readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

  public NoteService(IAuthenticationService authenticationService){
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }
//some code ...
}

public class CompanyNoteService : NoteService {
    
  public CompanyNoteService (IAuthenticationService authenticationService) : base (authenticationService) { }
  //some code...
  //overriding methods
}
```

Comment: Yes that was it